# Traefik Kubernetes: Expose non Kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

I'm using Kubernetes with Traefik as Ingress Controller. I've some web services within my network that can't be containerized yet. Therefore I'm looking for a way to expose my non-Kubernetes web services through the Traefik Ingress. I've no more public IP's, so splitting both environments is not an option.

I've made an endpoint + service to solve this issue, but when I try to connect I get an SSL Protocol Error. Am I doing something wrong or does someone have another solution?

These are my (test)endpoints and service yaml:

```
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 10.4.0.6
    ports:
      - port: 443
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    name: https
    targetPort: 443
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
  - host: host.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 443
```

Comment: what error do you see? Does it work if your backend is not on port 443 (not TLS). Did you setup your certificates?

Comment: @Rico All my backend services redirect to port 443. To test this scenario I've to deploy a port 80 test service. Chrome throws a ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, but that's a very generic error.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, I bet that when you `kubectl describe svc my-service` you have empty endpoints, even though endpoints do exist, right ?

To fix that, you need to adapt your endpoints `ports` key to have the same ports definition as your service has (name, protocol etc.). You should then see these endpoints in `describe service` results and be able to use it normally.

Comment: The ports where the same, but I hadn't specified the same port name. The endpoints is now showing when I describe my service. Still can't access the hostname tough, but I will troubleshoot some more.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this: Creating a K8s service of type ExternalName that binds to your external web service and add an Ingress as you would to with a "native" K8s service.

ExternalName Service --> https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname

Exp.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service 
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: prod
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: my.database.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

There we're multiple issue regarding this problem.
First of all I deployed Traefik with helm. I found out that SSL is disabled by default...

my values.yaml is as follows:

```
imageTag: 1.6.6
rbac:
  enabled: true
dashboard:
  enabled: true
  domain: traefik.dahsboard.local
ssl:
  enabled: true
  insecureSkipVerify: true
  upstream: true
```

Like Radek mentioned the port definition of the endpoints and service have to be the same.

mine are:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
    name: https
---
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
subsets:
  - addresses:
    - ip: 10.4.0.6
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      name: https
```